# Prevent domain from any data persistance

Tags: security, web

Is it possible to at a domain level (meta tag / HTTP header) to indicate to the web browser that no form of data persistence should be allowed.

Similar to how hsts tells the browser, you should ALWAYS expect to connect to this domain using SSL. Is there a way to tell you browser you should NEVER storage any for of data for this domain (Cookies / Local Storage / IndexDB) etc?